# C#: How to add a line to a memo?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a RichBox(memo) that I'd like to add lines to.

Currently,I use this

```
RichBox1.text += "the line I'd like to add" + "\n";
```

Isn't there something like the method in Delphi below?

```
Memo.Lines.add('The line I''d like to add');
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[AppendText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext(VS.71).aspx) is the closest it gets. Unfortunately you still have to append the newline character:

```
RichBox1.AppendText( "the line I'd like to add" + Environment.NewLine );
```

Comment: To avoid stuff appending you can use `string.Format`: `RichBox1.AppendText(string.Format("{0}{1}", "the line I'd like to add", Environment.NewLine));`

Answer (score 5):

You could use an extension method to add this handy `add` method to the RichTextBox class.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static void add(this System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox richText, string line)
    {    
       richText.Text += line + '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the AppendText method from TextBoxBaseand explicitly add the new line

```
RichBox1.AppendText("the line i'd like to add" + Environment.NewLine);
```